# Sum of measures and integral

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Suppose we have a measure that can be expressed as linear combination of 2 measures: $m=am_1+bm_2$. What does this imply for the calculation of the integral? Do we have:

$$\int f\,dm=a\int f\,dm_1 + b\int f\,dm_2$$

Here I consider a positive measure with $f$ some measurable map. The example I have in mind is the sum of dirac measures $1/2(\delta_0+\delta_1)$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works fine when all the measures are finite, or $a$ and $b$ are non-negative.

We can check the mentioned formula considering first simple functions (linear combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets), then jump to the general case approximating almost everywhere by a sequence of simple functions.

Comment: How about if the mixture is countably infinite, i.e. $m = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i m_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = 1$?

Comment: @aduh: perhaps the answer you are searching for is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896205/how-to-integrate-for-a-countable-sum-of-measures/2897713#2897713). The normalization condition $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n=1$ is in general not required, nor the finiteness of measures: however the uniform exaustiveness of the family of measures $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N a_n\right\}_{N\geq 1}$ is required and, as a matter of fact, is necessary and sufficient.