# Has Lebesgue integration been considered as "scalar multiplication" before?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

In light of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903250/rig-module-of-measures-with-scalar-multiplication-given-by-lebesgue-integrat) I simply wonder:

> whether any article or book has ever talked about Lebesgue integration
>   as a kind of scalar multiplication

with (possible signed) measures as "vectors" and nonnegative (or not) measurable functions into $[0\,..\infty]$ as "scalars" (specifically $f\cdot \mu$ is the indefinite integral of $f$ w.r.t. to $\mu$) or:

> whether any article or book has ever systematically used this notation for the indefinite integral to denote integrals in general (as opposed to using classical notation $\int\dots d\mu$).

(Remark: I *don't* claim there is a vector space structure or module structure here, but possibly (or definitely, see the linked question) something similar)

Comment: So they definitely don't form a vector space, that's just hopeless, since there's just no way to coerce such a space of functions into a field in any nice way. In terms of trying to identify a space of measures as a module, you also have some problems, because there are occasions when a measure multiplied by a signed function results in a "badly defined signed measure". One example is $\operatorname{sign}(x)dx$, which is (or at least can be identified with) a tempered distribution, but fails to be a signed measure.

Comment: Now one might be able to form a module out of a certain set $M$ of *finite* signed measures where the ring of "scalars" is $\bigcap_{m \in M} L^1(|m|)$. That might be an interesting question to look at.

Comment: @Ian I didn't know anything about the case of possibly negative functions or signed measures, but in the question linked it was established that it works for measures and nonnegative functions (they form a module over a rig/semiring in the obvious sense). I meant "vector" and "scalar" in a figurative sense.

Comment: @Ian: Instead of $\bigcap_{m \in M} L^1(|m|)$, I would take the underlying space to be topological and choose the ring of scalars to be the space of continuous, bounded functions. Alternatively, one might choose for vectors a *class of measures* (a set of finite, complex measures having the same null sets), whence the ring of scalars would naturally be $L^\infty$ of any of the measures in the class. (I don't understand why your intersection is non-trivial and a ring - the product of two functions in $L^1$ is not necessarily in $L^1$, and the problem is worse when we have multiple measures.)

Comment: Indeed, the construction proposed by @AlexM. is well-known in the theory of operator algebras as the bimodule structure of $A^\ast$ over $A$.

Comment: @AlexM. So many little places where infinities can creep up on you...nice setup.